# Zabbix proxy under error "failed to update local proxy configuration copy"

Tags: zabbix

This morning I've installed a Zabbix Proxy on an host and I've seen this message in the error log `/var/log/zabbix-proxy/zabbix_proxy.log` using the default `Template Linux`:

```
received configuration data from server at "<OMISSIS>", datalen 10911
failed to update local proxy configuration copy: invalid field name "interface.bulk"
```

Moreover I've inspected the `hosts` MySQL table of the Zabbix proxy and it has zero results, but I'm quite sure that the Zabbix proxy has lot of agents connected to it.

What's going on?

Updated:

My Zabbix server has version 4.0.4 and my Zabbix Proxy has version 5.0.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a Zabbix server with an old version and a Zabbix proxy with a recent version.

See version compatibility:

> To be compatible with Zabbix 5.4, the proxy must be of the same major version; thus only Zabbix 5.4.x proxies can work with Zabbix 5.4.x server.
> ― https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/appendix/compatibility

You can do one of these:

- update your Zabbix server
- downgrade your Zabbix proxy
- avoid the Zabbix proxy and just use Zabbix agents maybe in active mode